# Does this set span $\mathbb R^4$? What does a free variable mean in this case?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set $$A = \{(1, -2, -1, 1), (2, 1, 3, 2), (1, 1, 3, 1), (0, 1, 2, 0)\}$$ and would like to know if it spans $\mathbb R^4$.

---

I built an augmented matrix to check if linear combinations of the vectors of A can construct all vectors in $\mathbb R^4$.

Since there is a free variable, the system is still consistent. My initial thought was that the set does span $\Bbb R^4$, since the free variable must just mean that there are an infinite number of linear combinations of the vectors in the set, which will construct the vectors of $\Bbb R^4$. However, upon further reading, it seems like that is not what it means. In fact, the bits and pieces I've researched seem to indicate that a free variable in this case means that the set is NOT a spanning set?

In previous spanning set problems, I have only had consistent systems with unique solutions. Can someone please solve the above problem and detail what the free variable means in this case? In the context of spanning sets, what is the difference between getting a consistent system with a unique solution, and a consistent system with an infinite number of solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: what free variable? I don't see one in your post.

Comment: Since these are $4$ vectors in $\Bbb{R}^4$, they generate  $\Bbb{R}^4$ if and only if they are a basis. Again, this is equivalent on checking that they are linearly independent. Are you able to check whether they are linearly independent (for example, using the determinant)?

Comment: @JefLaga Row 4 - row 1 gives a row of zeros.

Comment: @Mattos is correct. I'm unsure why getting a consistent system with an infinite number of variables means that the set is not a spanning set for the space. From an intuitive perspective, it seems that it should mean that there are an infinite number of linear combinations for which we can get the vectors of R^4. However, that doesn't seem to be the case, since the set is not considered a spanning set? So what's the intuition behind this? What is it telling us about the spanning set that is different from the unique solution (which would mean it is a spanning set for R^4)? Thanks everyone.

Comment: Or, perhaps, am I looking at this the wrong way? Perhaps it's not the free variable (infinite solutions) that is indicating that it is not a spanning set. Is it, perhaps, the fact that the row of 0's has z - w to the right of the augmenting bar? In which case, we can interpret it to say that vectors in the space must have the condition z - w = 0. In this case, we would know the answer to obviously be false, since this cannot be true for all vectors in R^4? Is this where I misinterpreted the answer?

Comment: I think my post above was the answer. The row with all 0's specifies on the other side of the augmenting bar that z - w. Therefore, it's saying that z - w = 0. However, we know that this condition cannot be true for all vectors in R^4. Since this system does not satisfy all vectors in R^4, we know that the set must not be a spanning set for R^4! Thank you for your assistance everyone - I appreciate you taking the time to help a stranger out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my post above was the answer. The row with all 0's specifies on the other side of the augmenting bar that z - w (or whatever variables one chooses to represent the vectors of R^4). Therefore, it's saying that z - w = 0. However, we know that this condition cannot be true for all vectors in R^4. Since this system does not satisfy all vectors in R^4, we know that the set must not be a spanning set for R^4 - it only spans some vectors in R^4!

Thank you for your assistance everyone - I appreciate you taking the time to help a stranger out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

the four vectors are linearly independent (so they span $\mathbb{R}^4$) only if the determinant of the matrix that has such vectors as columns (or rows) is not null. In this case the determinant is null.

This means that the system:

$$
\begin {cases}
a+2b+c=0\\
-2a+b+c+d=0\\
-a+3b+3c+2d=0\\
a+2b+c=0
\end{cases}
$$
has a not trivial solution.In other words, there is a solution of the system with a free variable. So there are four numbers, not all null, such that:
$$
a\begin{bmatrix}
1\\-2\\-1\\1
\end{bmatrix}+
b\begin{bmatrix}
2\\1\\3\\2
\end{bmatrix}+
c\begin{bmatrix}
1\\1\\3\\1
\end{bmatrix}+
d\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1\\2\\0
\end{bmatrix}=0
$$

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, we were asked to justify the answer without using determinants. Can you or anyone else please provide a justification for why having a free variable in the system means that it is not a spanning set? For instance, I know that we are trying to see if every vector in R^4 can be built using linear combinations of the vectors in the set. Finding a unique solution to the system means that there is a certain linear combination that gets us the vectors of R^4. So what's different if we end up getting a free variable (infinite solutions), rather than the unique?

Answer (score 1):

This system of $4$ vectors spans (hence is a  basis of) $\mathbf R^4$ if  and only if they're linearly independent, i.e. (the matrix of) the associated system of linear equations has rank $4$.

We'll use row reduction to determine the rank of the system:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1&0\\
-2&1&1&1\\
-1&3&3&2\\
1&2&1&0
\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{\begin{aligned}R_2&\leftarrow R_2+2R_1\\R_3&\leftarrow R_2+R_1\\R_4&\leftarrow R_4-R_1\end{aligned}}
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1&0\\
0&5&3&1\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus the system has rank $3$, and the sytem of vectors generates a subspace of dimension $3$.